# How to say "Thanks for being my friend" for past friendship

Tags: phrases, past-tense

I need to send a card to refer to past friendship. Is

> Thanks for being my friend!

grammatically correct? I would not like to use the past perfect tense to express this (e.g. *had been*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind calling attention to the fact that the friendship has now ended, you can say *Thanks for having been my friend*.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply say

> Thanks for your friendship

in the card.

Comment: Thanks Jasper! It is an option. Although being Russian/Ukrainian native, it would be kind of odd